# Microsoft Graph SDK: Filter by Guid gives syntax error

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-sdks

Microsoft Graph Service Client C# v3.25

Without the filter it returns 90 assignments, trying to limit it to 1 Role

```
    var appRoleAssignedTo = await GraphClient.ServicePrincipals[entAppId].AppRoleAssignedTo
                .Request()
                .Filter($"AppRoleId eq {roleId}")
                .GetAsync();
```

Gives the error message

> ServiceException: Code: Request_BadRequest
> Message: Syntax error at position 21 in 'appRoleId eq 9e74ebe8-e458-4b1f-ab5c-e40d19a8e831'.

Also tried

```
.Filter($"AppRoleId eq '{roleId}'")
.Filter($"AppRoleId eq (guid'{roleId}')")
```

Resulting in

> ServiceException: Code: BadRequest
> Message: Invalid filter clause

Comment: I think the fillers that are manually entered in need to have a lowercase character first. Try “appRoleId” with a lowercase “a”. It gets confusing when dealing with the SDK because its members are all returned with uppercase. Try it in Graph Explorer to get the proper syntax. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

Comment: @general-gouda You can see in the error message it was converted to a lower case. I tried it with a lower case anyway and same error.

Comment: (1) can you share the detailed error response that you receive (including the requestid, timestamp? (2) Outside of SDK can you repro the issue with Graph Explorer/POSTMAN as well?

Comment: @Dev  Graph explorer does not have the required grants. I will attempt the queries in postman. There was no more info in the error message from GraphServiceClient